# Printing call-out borders in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, microsoft-word-2013

When I create a document including normal textboxes and call-outs, the borders of the call-outs print as thick even when I set the width to 0.25 (the minimum), but the textbox borders print fine.  This only happens in Word 2013 (works fine in Word 2010).  I've tried 3 different printers, and lots of printer drivers.

This is a major issue for us, as we produce all of our training courseware in Word and want to move onto the latest version (I'm loving the green alignment lines which appear when you move things to the margins).  Please can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I have wasted hours - probably days - on this problem, which no one in the world seems to experience.  It's happening on Word 2010 (sometimes) and Word 2013 (always), on 2 different models of HP laser printer and at least 3 different laptops.

The answer seems to be nothing to do with printer drivers or Word settings - it's just that as soon as you apply a different arrow ending to a call-out, it prints out with a thick line.

[image]

Can this really be true?  Please comment if you've had this problem!  I have now reverted to saving our documents in .doc format to get the line thickness correct for callouts and lines using arrow endings.